# tf. load_model returning Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: name

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

My cnn model contains a Lambda layer. when I load the model after saving model, the code throwing a error ”TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: name“.

```
def generate_matrix(input):
    ...

    return gram_output

def get_model():
    x = Input(shape = (300,300,3))
    vgg = VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
    feats = Model(vgg.input,vgg.get_layer("block5_conv1").output)
    for layer in feats.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    x1 = feats(x)
    x2 = Lambda(generate_matrix, name = "matrix")(x1)
    ...
    model = Model(inputs = x, outputs = predictions)
    model.summary()
    return model

model = get_model()
model.compile(...)
model.train(...)
model.save("my_model.h5")
```

load my model

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("my_model.h5",custom_objects ={"matrix": generate_matrix})
```

error:

```
TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: name
```

Howerer, there is no error when I load the weights of my model.

1.save weights of my model

```
model.save("my_model_weights.h5")
```

2.load weights

```
model = get_model()
model.load_weights("my_model_weights.h5")
```

3. save model

```
model.save("my_model2.h5")
```

4. load model

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("my_model.h5",custom_objects ={"matrix": generate_matrix})
```

it will success. why?

Comment: Did you train the model using keras and now you are loading it with tf.keras?

Comment: Can you post your optimizer?

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro  I always use tf.keras when training and loading

Comment: @Daniel Möller model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-5, momentum=0.9, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])